# How to implement custom annotation with parameters that returns on calling the function? Like @Query

Tags: java, spring, jpa, annotations, spring-data-jpa

How to implement some thing like @Query method of Spring-Data-JPA-Repository?

Instead of using @Query, I want to use my own annotation, but it should work the exact same way as @Query does.

For example, the method should get parameters and return some data.

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

  @Query("select u from User u where u.emailAddress = ?1")
  User findByEmailAddress(String emailAddress);
}
```

Maybe I sound stupid, but I want to implement some thing similar to this.

Comment: Read about reflection and dynamic proxies.

Comment: Thanks JB Nizet. You pointed me in the right direction. Now I have learnt how to do that.